Is spontaneous symmetry breaking possible without wave function collapse?
This is just a basic question to check my understanding (as a non-physicist).
An example to explain spontaneous symmetry breaking is given as follows: There is a particle that lies on the top of a local potential maximum symmetric in the $y$-axis. Hence the system is symmetric. When the particle falls down in one of the wells, the system is now asymmetric.

But my issue with this is:

Spontaneous symmetry breaking should be impossible in classical mechanics: If the particle is a classical point particle and was exactly at $x=0$ initially, and the system is deterministic, then it has to stay on top, so symmetry breaking doesn't occur. If it was only almost at $x=0$ (as in reality), then the initial state wasn't symmetric to begin with, so spontaneous symmetry breaking also doesn't occur.

Spontaneous symmetry breaking should be impossible even in quantum mechanics without wave function collapse. If the particle is instead a quantum particle, and the wave function is initially symmetric and mostly on top of the potential, then it will spread out and split symmetrically to both minima.

It seems like only if the wave function collapses to one side or the other that spontaneous symmetry breaking occurs.


Is my understanding correct?

You say "if the particle was exactly at $x=0$" and use a point particle to illustrate this in your drawing. But then you ask a question about a wave function! So the question is not clearly defined. What is your initial wave function? (If you give us that information, we just can see how the solution develops in time!)

@JosBergervoet, sorry, in my first bullet point I was talking about a classical model. I only started talking about a wave function in the second bullet point. Let me edit the question.

OK, probably I didn't read it well enough (distracted by the drawing, I guess...)

@JosBergervoet, I made it smaller, I hope this is better :S

You can actually make it smaller without uploading a low-resolution version, just using this syntax:
<img src="https://i.sstatic.net/3GUgZx3l.png" width="100">  (you can even do that with any existing external URL, but maybe SE prefers to have images uploaded into their system.)

Spontaneous symmetry breaking isn’t about an initially symmetric state evolving to an asymmetric state. It’s about a symmetric theory having asymmetric solutions.

@Ghoster But can that really be the essence? Any symmetric potential has asymmetric solutions...  I think most people would say it means something more special.

An initially symmetric wave function will remain symmetric, but for the system in isolation it will not really "fall to the bottom" since its energy cannot escape, it will just spread out (in a symmetric way).
More interesting is the case where there is interaction with the outside world. If the system can radiate energy it might end up in the ground state, but that is still a symmetric state for this potential. You could actually start with a non-symmetric state and let it radiate all its energy and that would look more like spontaneous symmetry creation! (But of course the asymmetry information would still be in the radiated field.)
What we're looking for here, is an end result that isn't the ground state, but one of the "left" and "right" states, shown as the dashed and dotted lines in this drawing: (where the red line is the ground state and the green one the first excited state)

Why would the solution ever be like that?! We know that it happens all the time, for instance a photon described by a plane (or spherical) wave can create one single dot on a photographic plate at only one of many possible positions. That's symmetry breaking! This brings us to the measurement problem. We know how QM can describe this kind of interaction with the environment and give as a result an entangled state, like:
$$
 |\psi\rangle = {\small\frac1{\sqrt2}}\big(\ \ |\psi_L\rangle_\text{sys}\ |\phi_A\rangle_\text{env} +  |\psi_R\rangle_\text{sys}\ |\phi_B\rangle_\text{env}\ \big)
$$
with $|\psi_L\rangle_\text{sys}$ and $|\psi_R\rangle_\text{sys}$ the left and right solutions for our subsystem and the $|\phi\rangle_\text{env}$ states describing the environment.
Where does this bring us? We know that we ourselves are part of the environment.  We also know that decoherence will (usually) occur, and then being in one term of the superposition, we do not observe the other term. We also know that (at least to speed up computations) we can then just act as if the other term of the superposition does not exist. We only do not know whether it really does not exist (that would require proof of the collapse of the wave function, you would have solved the measurement problem!)
So back to your question: can symmetry breaking occur "only if the wave function collapses"? That should be answered with no. The wave function may have collapsed or not, but we will still observe the same.
EDITED: (In view of the discussions)
It definitely is not trivial why we observe such asymmetric solutions, also not with the entangled state after interaction, because that could have been written differently:
\begin{align}
 |\psi\rangle &= {\small\frac1{\sqrt2}}\big(\ \ |\psi_L\rangle_\text{sys}\ |\phi_A\rangle_\text{env} +  |\psi_R\rangle_\text{sys}\ |\phi_B\rangle_\text{env}\ \big) \tag{1}
\\[6pt]
  &= {\small\frac12}\big(
\ \ |\psi_0\rangle_\text{sys}\ |\phi_A\!\!+\!\phi_B\rangle_\text{env}
+  |\psi_1\rangle_\text{sys}\ |\phi_A\!\!-\!\phi_B\rangle_\text{env}\ \big) \tag{2}
\end{align}
where $(1)$ and $(2)$ are the same since our system's left and right states $|\psi_L\rangle_\text{sys}$ and $|\psi_R\rangle_\text{sys}$ are just the combinations $|\psi_0\pm \psi_1\rangle_\text{sys}$ of the ground state and the first excited state.
If we take expression $(2)$ for the total state $|\psi\rangle$ after interaction then why can't we say that the state collapses into one of those two terms? (Or why can't we as observers be part of one of the states $|\phi_A\!\!+\!\phi_B\rangle_\text{env}$ and $|\phi_A\!\!-\!\phi_B\rangle_\text{env}$ in those terms?!)
The only solution is that the states used in $(1)$ are stable (so-called pointer states) and those in the terms of $(2)$ are not. To give that any meaning (stable against what?) you need to complicate things a bit further, see ["einselection"], which essentially says that due to further outside-world influences the terms in $(1)$ will merely get vastly fluctuating phase factors, while those in $(2)$ will start wildly mixing among each other.
Why this happens and why there is such a different behavior for pointer states and non-pointer states can be found elsewhere and is perhaps outside the scope of this question. (Although it is the only explanation we have for what the question is asking!)

There is no relation with the unfortunate concept of wave function collapse. The double well potential that you give has solutions that are even or odd under inversion, but still symmetric. It is only when there is a coupling with an underlying deforming degree of freedom that spontaneous symmetry breaking may occur. If the system deforms then the left or right well may become deeper and the other well shallower. Then the ground state will be a symmetric combination of the two possibilities with the particle (partially) localised in the deeper well, because these are still coupled by a hamiltonian element. If you start out with the particle on the left this hamiltonian element sets the time scale for it to oscillate between left and right. If this time scale is longer than the observation time, you will observe a broken symmetry. If this time scale is much shorter than the one governing the deformation, there will be no symmetry breaking.
An example of a very long time scale is a phosphorous atom in an infinite silicon crystal at 0 K. There is a very small probability of P hopping through the crystal, but the timescale at which this happens is huge. Strictly speaking, you could call this spontaneous symmetry breaking.

Here you require a "deforming" of the potential to get symmetry breaking. But that does not match with the concept of spontaneous symmetry breaking as we use, for instance, in the standard model for the weak interaction, where the potential does keep its symmetry all the time. (Making me wonder: Is there lack of consensus about what the concept spontaneous symmetry breaking actually means?!)

@JosBergervoet Interesting point. I'd have to look into it. First guess: the Mexican hat is already the result of such deformation.

A previous deformation could also be the case in OP's question (trying to stay OT in the comments!) but it wouldn't change the fact that the potential we have still possesses the symmetry we are discussing. Also, as far as it can be considered authoritative (speaking from Physics SE, after all) Wikipedia requires "while the underlying physical laws remain symmetrical" in their treatment of the concept: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spontaneous_symmetry_breaking#Overview

@JosBergervoet In my example the underlying laws are symmetric but they still result in a lower symmetry solution, which transforms as part of a degenerate representation. The potential effectively represents the rest of the system. The complete Hamiltonian is still symmetric.

But your example completely skips the process of symmetry breaking! Indeed the phosphorous atom's position has lost the symmetry of the lattice, but that happened when a plane wave (or alt least a broad beam) of phosphorus atoms was implanted and then evolved into this localized state on one particular lattice site. How did the wave function do that?! (It's the same as the dots on the photographic plate: the measurement problem!)

@JosBergervoet Does there have to be a process of symmetry breaking?

Yes, absolutely! Without it you would have the phosphorous atom in a superposition over all lattice sites (or at least within one reticle width of the wafer). How (and why) does the wave function change to the broken symmetry state, if the laws of physics and also the initial state are symmetric? The process only has to make us observe a specific non-symmetric result. If you invoke the many words view, then there is still the big superposition with the other outcomes of the symmetry breaking, so in that sense the total state does keep the symmetry (if you believe the MWI).
